# How to upgrade SystemD to 246+ on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, systemd-networkd

I'm using ROS on Ubuntu 20.04 with a CAN-FD adapter card. In systemd 246+ (20.04 uses 245), systemd-networkd adds support for CAN-FD specific settings to allow the system to boot automatically.

Is there a way for me to get systemd to a newer version without changing the version of Ubuntu (since I need to stay on 20.04 for the specific ROS integration)?

If I could follow instructions to compile a newer systemd, or just get a link to some suggestions, that would be very nice!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a high-risk operation since *systemd* is the start of a long dependency chain.

What you are asking for is basically to turn your Ubuntu 20.04 into a bleeding-edge system with new components on very deep system levels. You'd need a lot of expertise to do that successfully.

Also, are you sure that it's *systemd* that limits hardware compatibility with that CAN-FD card? Wouldn't that rather be kernel related?

Comment: I found this patch to networkd: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/e7b0ea544004fec4bb97f8db35942a196126cc8c

It's very small, but the first version it applies to is `246`. This is what's needed so that I don't need to manually type in `sudo ip link set can0 up mtu 72 type can bitrate 500000 dbitrate 500000 restart-ms 100 sample-point 0 dsample-point 0 fd on`. Do you have any thoughts on how you'd approach this?

Alternatively, do you have advice on how to approach rebuilding that one component? I'm sure I'm capable of backporting that patch, but not of how to rebuild a component.